# I want to place a div below a fixed image with auto height

Tags: javascript, height, margin, fixed

Maybe I'm not using the right keywords while searching, but I can't find a solution to my problem.

Here it is:

I have a fixed top banner image using 100% width and auto height. I would like to add my navigation and content right below it. The tricky thing is that I want the navigation and content to scroll over the image from below, while the image stays fixed on top of the page.

Is there a way to determine the height of the image (which will be relative to someone's screen size) and automatically use this as margin-top for the navigation div? That would theoretically fix my problem.

**edit; upon solving the initial problem, another one occurred. The #nav div now seems to think that the bottom of the #banner-image is the top of the screen. What could this be?**

Any other ideas are welcome!

Here's my code:

HTML

```
<img src="images/banner.jpg" id="banner" />

<div id="nav" >
    [...]
</div>
```

CSS

```
#banner {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}    

#nav    {
    background-color: #261E03;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can`t do that via CSS...
You can try using Jquery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#nav").css({
            "padding-top" : $("#banner").height()
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply!
I've tried several JS scripts that I've found while searching for an answer, but none of them seem to fix the problem. This one doesn't either. I have to add that JS isn't one of my strong points, so maybe I'm using it wrong... I assume this goes in the head section in between <script></script> tags?

Comment: Look at this JSFiffle, there it works! http://jsfiddle.net/aExWX/ Remember to call the JQuery script.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I guess I did something wrong there.
Now the second part of the problem kicks in. I don't know if you'd be able to help with that as well.
I'm using a script (stickyjs.com) to keep the nav fixed on top when scrolled to top position. The script now seems to think that the bottom of the banner-image is the top of the screen..